# react es6 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

i am working on an open source rails project which use react with rails, there is a feature called follow suggestion which shows users to follow, it has a refresh button to refresh new users but the refresh button is  not working, i checked everything and it looks good plus the server is also not giving any warning or error.

**followsuggestioncontainer.es6.jsx**

```
class FollowSuggestionsContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { 
      users: [],
      activeUsers: []
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchUsers();
    this.token = PubSub.subscribe('UserFollowButton:onClick', (message, data) => {
      this.removeUser(data.followed_id)
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    PubSub.unsubscribe(this.token);
  }

  fetchUsers() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/follow_suggestions.json',
      method: 'GET', 
      dataType: 'json',
      success: (data) => {
        const newActives = data.slice(0, 3)
        this.setState({ 
          activeUsers: newActives,
          users: [ ...data.slice(3), ...newActives ]
        });
      }
    });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="follow-suggestions-container border-top">
        <div className="suggestions-header">
          <h4 className="small-heading">People to follow</h4>
          <a className="refresh-link pull-right" onClick={this.refreshActiveUsers.bind(this)}>Refresh</a>
        </div>
        <div>
          {this.renderSuggestions()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderSuggestions() {
    if (this.state.users.length === 0) {
      return <h5>You are following all users!</h5>
    }
    return this.state.activeUsers.map(user => {
      return (
        <React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup
          key={user.id}
          transitionName="suggestion"
          transitionAppear={true}
          transitionAppearTimeout={500}
          transitionEnterTimeout={500}
          transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
        >
          <SuggestionItem key={user.id} {...user} />
        </React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup>
      )
    });
  }

  refreshActiveUsers() {
    const newActives = this.state.users.slice(0, 3);
    this.setState({
      activeUsers: newActives,
      users: [ ...this.state.users.slice(3), ...newActives ]
    });
  }

  removeUser(id) {
    const filteredUsers = this.state.users.filter(user => {
      if (user.id === id) {
        removedUser = user;
      }
      return user.id !== id;
    });

    this.setState({
      users: filteredUsers
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is not working?

Comment: Hey @Nick Wyman as you can see in the code there is a Refresh button which is suppose to refresh the user list... that's not working

Comment: I get that :) But I think we can go deeper into the details. Is it not calling refreshActiveUsers? Is it not making the API call you are expecting? Is it getting the new users, but not rendering them? Details like this will help.

Comment: @NickWyman exactly, it's not calling refreshActiveUsers